# Empty page when trying rendering data from an endpoint

Tags: node.js, react-native

I build an app with React-Native and I have created an endpoint from scratch using MySQL workbench with express and nodeJS.
Everything was fine until I tried to fetch all data from that endpoint so I can display it into Dom, unfortunately the output is empty, even though in the developers' tool I can see all the returned objects from the endpoint.
I don't know what is wrong in my code. Below you can see what I have done so far.

**Items.js:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  FlatList,
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
} from "react-native";
import axios from "axios";

const Items = () => {
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:3000/products/`)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        setProducts[res.data];
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  }, []);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {isLoading ? (
        <ActivityIndicator />
      ) : (
        <FlatList
          products={products}
          keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <Text>
              {item.id}, {item.name}, {item.price}, {item.category},{" "}
              {item.gender}, {item.brand}
            </Text>
          )}
        />
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 24,
  },
});

export default Items;
```

And  [A picture of the object I got when I console.log(res)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxCYC.png)

Comment: Can you add the print of `console.log(res)` to your question?

Comment: Hi akram-adel, I did it as you can see the code and I am getting all the data in the developer tool.

Comment: can you post the structure of your `res.data` ? i see the answer below is correct but you still have another error, just post it and we will help you find out.

Comment: Hi Khanh Le Tran, I have updated my question with a screen shoot of the data I am getting in the console. Just have a look and tell if I have to give more infos. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    import {
      ActivityIndicator,
      FlatList,
      Text,
      View,
      StyleSheet
    } from "react-native";
    
    const Items = () => {
      const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
      const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get(`http://localhost:3000/products/`)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
                setProducts(res.data.response);
                setLoading(false);
             })
             .catch((err) => {
                 console.error(err);
             });
       }, []);
    
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          {isLoading ? (
            <ActivityIndicator />
          ) : (
            <FlatList
              data={products}
              keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
              renderItem={({ item }) => (
                <Text>
                  {item.id}, {item.name}, {item.price}, {item.category},{" "}
                  {item.gender}, {item.brand}
                </Text>
              )}
            />
          )}
        </View>
      );
    };
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        padding: 24
      }
    });
    
    export default Items;
```

Comment: It worked  thanks a lot for all of you that help me in this issue

Comment: @SagharMirali, sorry for misunderstanding and it same. There was a mess in my code while trying to find a solution, as you can see in my last comment I have thank you all for your input to solve my problem. Again, I am very sorry.

Answer (score 1):

use `setProducts(res.data.response)` instead of `setProducts[res.data]` , and  `<FlatList data={products}` instead of  `<FlatList products={products}`

Comment: Hi Saghar Mirali, thanks for your feedback. When I changed setProducts(res.data) instead of setProducts[res.data] I get an error said:bundle.js:6930 Uncaught Invariant Violation: Tried to get frame for out of range index NaN
    at invariant (http://localhost:19006/static/js/bundle.js:6930:15)
    at VirtualizedList._this._getFrameMetrics (http://localhost:1900.  And changing from <FlatList data={products} instead of <FlatList products={products} it seems logic but the problem still there.

Comment: what type is your res.data? is that array or object or ... ? can you add your console.log(res) result to your question?

Comment: I have edited my question, it is an object I got in the console

Comment: it is an array that contains 15 objects. you should write setProducts(res.data.response) beacause your items are inside res.data.response not res.data

Comment: there is no changes even when I change from setProducts(res.data.) to setProducts(res.data.response)